# Integration a zero valued function product other function

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

Suppose I have a function $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ except $0$. Now, $f(x) g(x)$ will also be zero for all $x$ except $0$ (or may be at $0$). Now, if try to find the value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$, since this will give area of the graph, then I think it must be $0$.

But, is it possible for the integral to get some finite value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dealing with this formally involves working with measure theory and Lebesgue integrals, but broadly speaking if $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ except for a finite number of isolated points where it has a finite value, then $\int f(x) dx = 0$ over any interval. So then $f(x) g(x)$, since it will also be zero almost everywhere, will also have integral zero. This is exactly as you've guessed, because the graph has zero area.

Now, if $f(0)$ is infinite, it's a bit harder to deal with. The Dirac delta function (which is not quite a function in the normal sense, despite the name) is defined to be zero everywhere, except $\delta(0)$ where it spikes infinitely high in such a way that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) g(x) dx = g(0)$. That's kind of beyond basic calculus though so for all intents and purposes you can ignore that kind of stuff and just assume "infinity is weird".

Comment: You can also do it with Riemann integration.

Comment: Can you give me a hint for how to do it?

Comment: If you create upper and lower Riemann sums for the integral, then the only rectangle that will have non-zero area is the one that includes $x = 0$. As the width of that rectangle approaches zero, what happens to its area?

Comment: But that is not a rectangle since width is actually 0 and not approaching to 0

Comment: In the limit maybe, but you construct your Riemann sum using rectangles of non-zero width.